# Factorise $1+x^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

How do I factorise this expression?

$$1+x^2$$

An attempt: complete the square $(1-x)(1+x).$ teacher said no.

$x(1/x+x)$ again teacher said no.

She said is related to solving this $x^2+1=0$.

I got no idea, can anyone help me to solve it?

Comment: Do you know of complex numbers?

Comment: Do you know about imaginary numbers ($i^2 =-1$)?

Comment: $(x-i)(x+i)$ where$ i=\sqrt{-1}$

Comment: @Tojrah $i\neq\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: What do you mean by factorise? That is, are the factors allowed to have any coefficients?

Comment: What do you mean? @amsmath

Comment: @Tojrah $\sqrt{-1}$ does not exist. And no, even not as a complex number. $i$ is defined as a number with the property $i^2 = -1$, that's all. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit#Proper_use

Comment: How exactly did you “complete the square?” You should check your own work: what do you get when you multiply out $(1+x)(1-x)$? It’s certainly not $1+x^2$.

Comment: @amsmath I predict most would agree that $\sqrt{-1}$ is the notation for the principle square root of negative one. While you are free to disagree or to introduce ambiguity, it is standard.

Comment: @DavidPeterson No, it isn't. Because it's wrong.

Comment: You need complex numbers here. Nothing which is considered in precalculus I guess.

Comment: @amsmath, you do realize that there is a way to define $z\mapsto \sqrt z\,\colon \mathbb C\to\mathbb C$? Choose, for example, principal branch, and let $\sqrt z = e^{1/2 \ln z}$. One can look at the limit $\lim_{\vartheta\to \pi^-}\sqrt {e^{i\vartheta}}$ to get $\sqrt{-1} = i$. The function won't be continuous on whole $\mathbb C$, but $\sqrt{-1} = i$ is very common and useful. [Principal square root of a complex number.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number)

Comment: @Ennar Yes, I realize that, but this function (you can define infinitely many of them) is not commonly used. If $i = \sqrt{-1}$ is really common, then it's just stupid and no -- it's not useful (show me where it is). I once more refer to the section in Wikipedia:  https://www.en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit#Proper_use

Comment: @amsmath, solve $x^2+2x+2=0$ using quadratic formula. Also, I love how that section starts with sentence: "The imaginary unit is sometimes written $\sqrt{-1}$ in advanced mathematics contexts (as well as in less advanced popular texts)."

Answer (score 1):

In context:

$y=1+x^2.$

Assume there is a factorization

$(x^2+1)=(x-a)(x-b)$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, then

$a,b$ are the real roots , i.e.

$1+a^2=0$, and $1+ 1+ b^2=0$.

But: $y=1+x^2 >0$ (why?) for $x \in.\mathbb{R}.$

Hence no factorization in $ \mathbb{R}.$

But we know that a polynomial of degree $2$ has $2$ roots:

The roots are complex, refer to ProblemBook's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply these $(x-i)(x+i)$, where $i$ is the imaginary unit with the property that $i^2=-1$, you will get your expression.

Comment: What is $\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: It is not not a real number...so called complex number.

Comment: No, also in the complex numbers $\sqrt{-1}$ is undefined. What you mean is $i$, the imaginary unit.

Comment: @ProblemBook Technically, you could always write $0+\sqrt{-1}$. That is a complex number.

Comment: @Antinous Nope. $\sqrt{-1}$ is not defined.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking that we actually compute $\sqrt{-1}$? This is not so. Most people agree to define that symbol to be the ordered pair $(0,1)$, which is also commonly defined to be the imaginary unit denoted by $i$. These are symbols only. Symbols can be defined in any which way you like. You can define the complex numbers as ordered pairs $(a,b)$ with (one) property (being) $$(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac-bd, ad+bc),$$ in which case I define the symbol (note not plural) $\sqrt{-1}$ to be the ordered pair $(0,1)$. Clearly then $(0,1)\cdot(0,1)=(-1,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Why don't you listen to the teacher and solve the equation ?

$$x^2+1=0\iff x^2=-1\iff x=\pm i.$$

Then as the polynomial has these roots, it must be proportional to the binomials $(x-i)$ and $(x+i)$, which vanish at these roots.